# How to hide primefaces menubar on mouseout

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I need to get `p:menubar` to hide on `mouseout`. How can I get this?
Tried override `PrimeFaces.widget.Menubar.prototype` methods, but all times  something is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next solution works for me. I start timer to hide all on deactivate, clear it on activate and reactivate.

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Menubar.prototype.deactivate = function(b, a) {
       var menu = this;
       menu.activeitem = null;
       b.children("a.ui-menuitem-link").removeClass(
                    "ui-state-hover ui-state-active");
       b.removeClass("ui-menuitem-active ui-menuitem-highlight");
       if (a) {
             b.children("ul.ui-menu-child").fadeOut("fast");
       } else {
             b.children("ul.ui-menu-child").hide();
             if (!this.timer) {
                    this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                           menu.reset();
                    }, 300);
             }
       }
}

PrimeFaces.widget.Menubar.prototype.reactivate = function(d) {
       if (this.timer) {
             clearTimeout(this.timer);
             this.timer = null;
       }
       this.activeitem = d;
       var c = d.children("ul.ui-menu-child"), b = c
                    .children("li.ui-menuitem-active:first"), a = this;
       if (b.length == 1) {
             a.deactivate(b)
       }
}

PrimeFaces.widget.Menubar.prototype.activate = function(b) {
       if (this.timer) {
             clearTimeout(this.timer);
             this.timer = null;
       }
       this.highlight(b);
       var a = b.children("ul.ui-menu-child");
       if (a.length == 1) {
             this.showSubmenu(b, a)
       }
}
```

Comment: thank you! this worked for me in 2022. Using PrimeFaces version 11.

Comment: nice clean solution, thank you. please also see PF issue 10728 for gettin' this functionality built in: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10728